# In emacs loading mail client wanderlust stucks in semi-def.el --> void-function static-cond

Tags: emacs, elisp, common-lisp

the first time for me to ask something here although I took a lot of benefits as reader since years.

I have a problem regarding loading in emacs 24.4.1 the mail client wanderlust in its newest version fom melpa.org. I solved all dependencies and added all packages (flim, semi, apel) to my load path. But despite of it I got throwing an error during load procedure.

I tried to load emacs in debug mode and got the error focused in the the file semi-def.el, where the following error pop up:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function static-cond)
(static-cond ((featurep (quote xemacs)) (defalias (quote mime-should-use-popup-menu) (function (lambda nil (and window-system (mouse-event-p last-command-event))))) (defalias (quote mime-select-menu-alist) (function (lambda (title menu-alist) (if (mime-should-use-popup-menu) (let (ret) (popup-menu ...) (recursive-edit) ret) (cdr (assoc ... menu-alist))))))) (t (defalias (quote mime-should-use-popup-menu) (function (lambda nil (and window-system (memq (event-basic-type last-command-event) (quote ...)))))) (defalias (quote mime-select-menu-alist) (function (lambda (title menu-alist) (if (mime-should-use-popup-menu) (x-popup-menu (list ... ...) (list title ...)) (cdr (assoc ... menu-alist))))))))
```

It seems to me that it can't be an error in the file itself. I guess there is somthing wrong in the interpretation of that function, which my emacs version is still missing for a proper interpretation something like a missing library. I tried also in that file to replace

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
```

with

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))
```

But no success so far.
Any help in the issue is much appreciated.
Regards Falk

Comment: Find out which library defines `static-cond` and `load` or `require` that library **before** the file that contains the code mentioned underneath the first line of the error message in your question.  I combined everything into one very long file as a custom setup, so I'd need to download and grep the various libraries -- something which you can do also.  It will look something like this:  `(defmacro static-cond (&rest clauses) . . .`  And likewise, grep for the second line of debugger message so you can find out what file it is and ensure that it loads **after**.

Comment: I wonder what this `static-cond` is ... perhaps a macro that runs the given tests at expansion time and expands into the respective form? That shouldn't be too hard to write, if all else fails.

Comment: It is in `static.el`:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/APortableEmacsLibrary

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it. File static.el was the point.